# Zend Framework 2 - How to upload multiple files?

Tags: zend-framework2

How to upload multiple files in Zend Framework 2. I have done this work. But, i got the following error for second file.

```
'first-filename' was illegally uploaded. This could be a possible attack.
```

For your reference,

```
            $size   = new Size(array('max' => 1048576));
            $adapter= new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); 
            $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('logo');
            $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $File['name']);
            $FileName   = '';

            if (!$adapter->isValid()){
                $dataError = $adapter->getMessages();
                $error = array();
                foreach($dataError as $key=>$row)
                {
                    $error[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $adapter->setDestination(path);
                if ($adapter->receive($File['name'])) {
                    // manipulation
                }
            }

            $logoFile   = $this->params()->fromFiles('logo2');
            $adapterLogo    = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); 
            $adapterLogo->setValidators(array($size), $logoFile['name']);
            $logoFileName= '';

            if (!$adapterLogo->isValid()){
                $dataError = $adapterLogo->getMessages();
                $error = array();
                foreach($dataError as $key=>$row)
                {
                    $error[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $adapterLogo->setDestination(path2);
                if ($adapterLogo->receive($logoFile['name'])) {
                    // manipulation
                }
            }
```

How can i solve this issue? Why this error occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made sure you have the correct enc type on your form?

```
$form->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');
```

Add the filename into the isValid check too

```
if($adapterLogo->isValid('logo2')) { /** .. **/ }
```

It's much simpler if you use Forms to valide this for you reather than using the validator like that, see this example:

http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/

Comment: Yes. first file has been uploaded. Could not upload the second file.

Comment: Thanks. Little bit improvement in output. I have followed your soln. I can upload the different files in first and second file upload. If i upload the same file in both first and second file upload, it's not working.